# How to call a method from another method in objective C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
-(void) callme {
//statements
here I call another method "callmeagain"
}
```

}

But it is not working. Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To call an ObjC method, use the syntax `[foo methodName:param andAlso:param2 …]` In your case, try

```
-(void)callme {
  [self callmeagain];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another Method could be

```
[self performSelector:@selector(callmeagain)];
```

It is basically the same thing as Kenny's Suggestion