# How to call a method inside another method in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm new to Objective-C.

If I wrote this method declaration in `.h`

```
-(void)myMethod;
```

and this implementation in `.m`

```
-(void)myMethod{
    NSLog(@"This is myMethod");
}
```

How can I call it in my class' `viewDidLoad` method?

Thank you.

Comment: for ages when i started iphone dev, i scratched my head woundering the same thing!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call a method from another method in objective C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438442/how-to-call-a-method-from-another-method-in-objective-c)

Comment: It is a basic programming strategy. You should go through http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cts=1331459307283&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Fdocumentation%2Fcocoa%2Fconceptual%2Fobjectivec%2Fobjc.pdf&ei=6HRcT6egJoTlrAedubCCDA&usg=AFQjCNHsX8x0OIGisCbmOfBwS80xXZXzCg&sig2=qA5xK47lKMWko6DqwLNS_g

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply just use object "self"

`[self myMethod];`

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that `-viewDidLoad` is in the same class, use

```
[self myMethod];
```

`self` here is an automatic reference to the current object instance.  If you want to call a method on another object stored in a pointer `otherObj`, it would be

```
[otherObj myMethod];
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you're calling `myMethod` on the same class as what implements `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    //...other code
    [self myMethod];
    //...other code
}
```

If you are having trouble with basic Objective-C though, I'd strongly suggest to either get a decent book on Objective-C, such as:

- [**Programming in Objective-C 2.0**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321566157) by **Stephen Kochan**
- [**Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321503619) by **Aaron Hillegass**
- [**iPhone Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321706242) by **Joe Conway** & **Aaron Hillegass**

…or at least read a **good beginners tutorial**, such as:
http://www.cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/

There are quite a **few more helpful beginners tutorials** by **Scott Stevenson** here:
http://www.cocoadevcentral.com/

Answer (score 2):

```
[self methodname];
```

will  work.